# Blender Texture Seam

Tags: textures, models, blender

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/the-secrets-of-realistic-texturing/) to create a brushed metal "start" button. (I am very new to all of this) I want the button to look nice when rendered in a game engine.

For some reason I can not figure out how to get the texture to wrap cleanly without seams. I modeled the "pill" part of the button using mirror and subsurf modifiers. The texture is a free version from cgtextures that is supposedly ready to be tiled. I created the various textures (normal/specular/etc) using CrazyBump as mentioned in the tutorial.

But now I'm stuck! The seems are driving me insane

[image]

Comment: This looks more like a mirror-modifier issue than a texturing problem. Your mirror-modifier should be before the subsurf-modifier. Also you have to select "Merge" and maybe increase the "Merge Limit". And make sure you don't have any faces on the mirror-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look up how to unwrap and layout your UVs.

Here is a link to get you started:

http://3d.about.com/od/3d-101-The-Basics/a/Surfacing-101-Creating-A-UV-Layout.htm

The tutorial you are following is laying out a texture on a plane, and so his texture is not wrapping around a 3D object.  When apply 2D texture to a 3D object the UVs need to be laid out correctly so that it hides the seam or is unnoticeable.

I haven't done 3D work in a while, but I hope this helps.

Comment: I have done "UV unwrapping" and it didn't seem to help. The object looks fine at the beginning of the tutorial but as soon as I add on normal mapping it gets the strange seems again.

Changing the "Normal Map" from "Vector Space" to "Object Space" however made it look just fine. Any idea what is going on?